# gid is putting labels in the main window instead of the frames within which they belong

Tags: python, tkinter, gridview

The following code gives weird output.

```py
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.config(bg='white')
LabelFrame.configure(root, bg='white')

nw = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is one').grid(row=0, column=0)
label1 =    Label(nw, text='000')
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 =    Label(nw, text='001')
label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
label3 =    Label(nw, text='002')
label3.grid(row=0, column=2)
label4 =    Label(nw, text='003')
label4.grid(row=0, column=3)
#
ne = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is two').grid(row=0, column=1)
label5 =    Label(ne, text='010')
label5.grid(row=0, column=0)
label6 =    Label(ne, text='011')
label6.grid(row=0, column=1)
label7 =    Label(ne, text='012')
label7.grid(row=0, column=2)
label8 =    Label(ne, text='013')
label8.grid(row=0, column=3)
#
sw = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is three').grid(row=1, column=0)
labell9 =   Label(sw, text='100')
labell9.grid(row=0, column=0)
label20 =   Label(sw, text='101')
label20.grid(row=0, column=1)
label21 =   Label(sw, text='102')
label21.grid(row=0, column=2)
label22 =   Label(sw, text='103')
label22.grid(row=0, column=3)
#
se = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is four').grid(row=1, column=1)
label13 =   Label(se, text='110')
label13.grid(row=0, column=0)
label14 =   Label(se, text='111')
label14.grid(row=0, column=1)
label15 =   Label(se, text='112')
label15.grid(row=0, column=2)
label16 =   Label(se, text='113')
label16.grid(row=0, column=3)

import tkcap
tkcap.CAP(root).capture('weirdgrid.png')
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

While it should give a nice grid that would look something like this after being populated with data.

[image]

i.e. the numbers (000, 001, 002 etc) should appear as rows, in first column, in each quadrant (nw, ne, sw and se).

Comment: I recommend you examine the value of `nw`, `ne`, `sw`, and `se` to see if they are what you're assuming they are set to.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the type and it returned 'NoneType' so I separated the label definition and positioning in two lines.

`sw = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is three')
sw.grid(row=1, column=0)`

Comment: If you solved the problem, close it by answering your own question.

Comment: @relent95 it solved one problem but solved the question yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to my own question.

```py
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np
arr4 = np.array(np.arange(1,257)).reshape(-1,4,4)
dfs = [pd.DataFrame(i, index=["row1", "row2", "row3", "row4"], columns=["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"]) for i in arr4]
root = Tk()
counter = 0
frames = []
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        frame = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text = "_".join(["product", str(j)]))
        frames.append(frame)
        frame.grid(row=i,column=j, sticky="EW")
        Label(frames[counter], text="_".join(["Calls",str(counter)])).grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="EW")
        for k in range(4):
            Label(frames[counter], text="".join(["column ",str(k+1)])).grid(row=0,column=k*2+1, sticky="EW", columnspan=2) # columns
            Label(frames[counter], text="".join(["row ", str(k+1)])).grid(row=k+1,column=0, sticky="EW", columnspan=1) # rows
            for m in range(4):
                data = dfs[counter]
                value = data.iloc[k][m]
                Label(frames[counter], text=value).grid(row=k+1,column=m*2+1, sticky="E", columnspan=1) # numbers in the table
                if m == 0: continue
                Label(frames[counter], fg = 'red', font="bold", text="^").grid(row=k+1,column=m*2+2, sticky="W", columnspan=1) # numbers in the table
        counter+=1

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not uncertainly if this is what you wanted like this. Unfortunately, you are mixed up `row` and `column` index.

I commented out in line 52 and 53, `#import tkcap` and `#tkcap.CAP(root).capture('weirdgrid.png')`

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.config(bg='white')
LabelFrame.configure(root, bg='white')

nw = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is one')
nw.grid(row=0, column=0)
label1 =    Label(nw, text='000')
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2 =    Label(nw, text='001')
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
label3 =    Label(nw, text='002')
label3.grid(row=2, column=0)
label4 =    Label(nw, text='003')
label4.grid(row=3, column=0)
#
ne = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is two')
ne.grid(row=0, column=1)

label5 = Label(ne, text='010')
label5.grid(row=0, column=0)
label6 =    Label(ne, text='011')
label6.grid(row=1, column=0)
label7 =    Label(ne, text='012')
label7.grid(row=2, column=0)
label8 =    Label(ne, text='013')
label8.grid(row=3, column=0)
#
sw = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is three')
sw.grid(row=1, column=0)

labell9 =   Label(sw, text='100')
labell9.grid(row=0, column=0)
label20 =   Label(sw, text='101')
label20.grid(row=1, column=0)
label21 =   Label(sw, text='102')
label21.grid(row=2, column=0)
label22 =   Label(sw, text='103')
label22.grid(row=3, column=0)
#
se = LabelFrame(root, width=270, height=130, text='This is four')
se.grid(row=1, column=1)
label13 =   Label(se, text='110')
label13.grid(row=0, column=0)
label14 =   Label(se, text='111')
label14 .grid(row=1, column=0)
label15 =   Label(se, text='112')
label15.grid(row=2, column=0)
label16 =   Label(se, text='113')
label16.grid(row=3, column=0)

#import tkcap
#tkcap.CAP(root).capture('weirdgrid.png')
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]